# How to get to the bottom of a stack (without losing the other elements) in Java

Tags: java, boolean, stack

I needed to create a BitOutputStream by creating a Stack type Boolean, and then output the Bytes that were "stored" in that stack.

```
package cop2805;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BitOutputStream {
    
    Stack<Boolean> buffer;
    
    BitOutputStream(){
        buffer = new Stack<Boolean>();
    }
    public void WriteBit(char bit) {
        Path path = Paths.get("bits.bin");
        try {
            OutputStream bitOut = Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                    StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            BufferedOutputStream buffered =
            new BufferedOutputStream(bitOut);
            buffered.write(bit);
                     if (bit == '1') {
                         buffer.push(true);
                     }
                     else {
                         buffer.push(false);
                     }
                if (buffer.size() == 8) { //stack reaches 8 bits
                    OutputByte();
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("error: %s%n", e);
        }
    }
    public void close(){ //outputs any remaining bits in the buffer.
        byte b = 0;
        int exp = 1;
        while(!buffer.empty()) {
            buffer.pop();
            if (buffer.contains(true)) {
                b += exp;
            }
            exp *= 2;
        }
        System.out.printf("\nBytes: %d", b);
        
    }

    private void OutputByte(){
        byte b = 0;
        int exp = 1;
        while(!buffer.empty()) {
            System.out.println(buffer.pop());
             if (buffer.contains(true)) {
                 b += exp;
             }
             exp *= 2; //increase the exponent by a power of 2
        }
         System.out.printf("Bytes: %d", b);
    }
}
```

It's working well, until I have to go through the stack and have it convert the bits into decimal bytes. As since it's working from the last element put into said stack, the byte that is outputted is wrong. The first 8 bits should be a byte size of 110 (the bits are 0110 1110), but its outputting 63 since its working with bits 0111 0110.
Any way to get to the bottom of the stack without using pop method as that'll remove that element from the stack?

Comment: You can push them into *another* stack so they can be recovered.

Comment: @Scott-Hunter Ah okay, so for example it'd be something along the lines of like `newStack.push(buffer.peek());` ?

Comment: Why are you using a stack when what you need is a queue?

Comment: @user207421 read the answer replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a queue which is FIFO (first in first out) instead of a stack which is FILO (first in last out) you will be able to read the bits in the proper order without any other manipulation.

If you `push()` 0101 to a stack when you `pop()` all elements, you will get 1010

If you `add()` 0101 to a queue when you `poll()` all elements, you will get 0101

**EDIT:**

I think I realized why your assignment requires you to use a stack. When your program reads from a file it will read the binary values left to right, but binary is read right to left (starting with the least significant digit). Since the order is reversed, a stack (FILO) **IS** the appropriated data structure to use.

When I run the following code with 01101110 as input, it outputs "Bytes: 110" as it should.

```
byte resultByte = 0;
int exp = 1;

while(!buffer.empty()) {
    boolean bit = buffer.pop();
    if (bit)
        resultByte += exp;
    exp *= 2;
}

System.out.println("Bytes: " + resultByte);
```

Comment: Yes, but I was needed to create a Stack for my assignment so I cannot use a queue sadly. I went and did what Scott suggested which worked, but the bytes are being outputted wrong still. Is `if (buffer.contains(true))` the proper way to see if what is in the stack does equal true? Because by debugging I see that in every condition true or false, it goes into my if statement. What am i doing wrong there? (This is relating to my OutputByte function).